# Initial Route if user is logged Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a Future to know if the user is logged, but the initial route isn't save. Then I recive this route in the Initial Route of my material app.

```
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await UserProvider().isUserLoggedIn();
  runApp(MiRoulotte());
}
 
class MiRoulotte extends StatelessWidget {
  final _userProvider = UserProvider();
  ...
        initialRoute: _userProvider.initialRoute,
        routes: {
          'InitialPage': (BuildContext context) => InitialPage(),
          'SignIn': (BuildContext context) => SignInPage(),
          'SignUp': (BuildContext context) => SignUpPage(),
          'EditProfile': (BuildContext context) => EditProfilePage()
        },
      )
    );
  }
}

Future isUserLoggedIn() async{
        var user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
        if(user != null){
          try{
            this._currentUser = await getUser(user.uid);
            this._initialRoute = 'InitialPage';
          }catch(error){
            this._initialRoute = 'SignIn';
          }
        } else{
          this._initialRoute = 'SignIn';
        }
      }
    }
```

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Auhl8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating two different instances of `UserProvider`, that's the problem. You assign the `_initialRoute` on the first one, but then create a second one which i't assigned.

If you are using `Provider`, you should use the same instance for that tree and then get it retrieve it through a `Consumer` for example. Replace your main with:

```
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  UserProvider userProvider = UserProvider();
  await userProvider.isUserLoggedIn();
  runApp(
      Provider<UserProvider>(
        create: (_) => userProvider,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) => child,
        child: MiRoulotte()),
      ),
    );
}
```

And then your `MiRoulotte` fetch it in your `build` method using a `Consumer` widget or explicit variable assign:

```
UserProvider _userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);
```

This way you ensure that you are using always the same instance.